# How to fetch typical json data using Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, fetch

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ResumedataService
} from "../../services/resumedata.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {
  projectdata: any = [];
  constructor(private resumeservice: ResumedataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // service call
    this.resumeservice.getresumedata().subscribe(data => (this.projectdata = data.projects));
  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of projectdata">
  <h5>{{item.projectName}}</h5>
  <span>{{item.technologies.tech}}</span>
</div>

//******this is jason data******* "projects": [ { "id":1, "projectName": "Flight Reservation System", "technologies": [ {"tech":"html"}, {"tech":"css"}, {"tech":"javascript"}, {"tech":"jquery"}, {"tech":"sql"}, {"tech":"angular"} ] }, { "id":2, "projectName":
"Train Reservation System", "technologies": [ {"tech":"html"}, {"tech":"css"}, {"tech":"javascript"}, {"tech":"jquery"}, {"tech":"sql"}, {"tech":"angular"} ] } ]
```

Above is my source code as you can see i want to fetch data through as I am successfully getting the name of the project but the object called "technologies" has children so how can I fetch them take a look if there is any mistake..??

Comment: can you try with item['projectName']

Comment: `this.projectdata = data.projects, this.technologydata = data.technologies`

Comment: You can read about [how to access data in angular](https://codesearchable.com/es/3572206/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

projects.technologies is also an array, so you also need to iterate through them.

f.e.:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of projectdata">
  <h5>{{item.projectName}}</h5>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let technologie of item.technologies">
    <span>{{technologie.tech}}</span>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use another `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  {{item.projectName}}
  <br />
  <ul *ngFor="let t of item.technologies">
    <li>{{t.tech}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xsmgy?file=src/app/app.component.html

Hope it helps!